# Filter dataframe based on a separate reference table

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have data that I need to clean up programmatically using a reference table. In the reference table, each row pertains to a different column in the data, and specifies the values by which to filter each data variable.

### Example

*Data*

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_mtcars <-
  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("cars")
```

*Reference Table*

```r
filter_ref_table <-
  structure(
  list(
    var_name = c(
      "disp",
      "wt",             
      "gear",          
      "carb",
      "mpg",
      "cars",           
      "drat"
    ),
    filtering_values = list(
      NULL,
      structure(
        list(
          min = 3.4,
          max = 3.9,
          values = list(NULL)
        ),
        class = c("tbl_df",
                  "tbl", "data.frame"),
        row.names = c(NA,-1L)
      ),
      structure(
        list(
          min = NA_integer_,
          max = NA_integer_,
          values = list(c(3))
        ),
        class = c("tbl_df",
                  "tbl", "data.frame"),
        row.names = c(NA,-1L)
      ),
      NULL,
      NULL,
      structure(
        list(
          min = NA_integer_,
          max = NA_integer_,
          values = list(c("Maserati Bora", "Chrysler Imperial", "Toyota Corona", "Merc 450SE", 
                          "Lincoln Continental", "Mazda RX4", "Valiant", "Hornet 4 Drive", 
                          "Fiat X1-9", "Camaro Z28", "Fiat 128", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
                          "Merc 240D", "Duster 360"))
        ),
        class = c("tbl_df",
                  "tbl", "data.frame"),
        row.names = c(NA,-1L)
      ),
      NULL
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-7L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

filter_ref_table

## # A tibble: 7 x 2
##   var_name filtering_values
##   <chr>    <list>          
## 1 disp     <NULL>          
## 2 wt       <tibble [1 x 3]>
## 3 gear     <tibble [1 x 3]>
## 4 carb     <NULL>          
## 5 mpg      <NULL>          
## 6 cars     <tibble [1 x 3]>
## 7 drat     <NULL>
```

When taking a closer look at `filter_ref_table`, we can unnest the list-column `filtering_values` and see how it's constructed inside: a nested tibble with 3 columns: `min`, `max`, and `values`.

```r
filter_ref_table %>% 
  filter(var_name == "wt") %>% 
  unnest(filtering_values)

## # A tibble: 1 x 4
##   var_name   min   max values
##   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <list>
## 1 wt         3.4   3.9 <NULL> ## when there are min/max values we know we should filter by this range

##############################################################################

filter_ref_table %>% 
  filter(var_name == "cars") %>% 
  unnest(filtering_values)        
                                  

## # A tibble: 1 x 4
##   var_name   min   max values    
##   <chr>    <int> <int> <list>    
## 1 cars        NA    NA <chr [15]>   ## when there are values inside "value" we know that we should 
#                              ↑         ## filter to keep any data rows that have either of these values
#                              ↑ 
#   [1] "Maserati Bora"       "Chrysler Imperial"   "Toyota Corona"      
#   [4] "Merc 450SE"          "Lincoln Continental" "Mazda RX4"          
#   [7] "Valiant"             "Hornet 4 Drive"      "Fiat X1-9"          
#   [10] "Camaro Z28"          "Fiat 128"            "Mazda RX4 Wag"      
#   [13] "Datsun 710"          "Merc 240D"           "Duster 360"                  


#############################################################################################
filter_ref_table %>% 
  filter(var_name == "gear") %>% 
  unnest(filtering_values) %>%
  unnest(values)

## # A tibble: 1 x 4
##   var_name   min   max values
##   <chr>    <int> <int>  <dbl>
## 1 gear        NA    NA      3
```

So based on `filter_ref_table`, we know that we need to filter rows in `my_mtcars` like that:

```r
expected_output <- 
  my_mtcars %>%
  filter(cars %in% c("Maserati Bora", "Chrysler Imperial", "Toyota Corona", "Merc 450SE", 
                     "Lincoln Continental", "Mazda RX4", "Valiant", "Hornet 4 Drive", 
                     "Fiat X1-9", "Camaro Z28", "Fiat 128", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
                     "Merc 240D", "Duster 360")) %>%
  filter(gear == 3) %>%
  filter(between(wt, 3.4, 3.9))

> expected_output

##         cars  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## 1    Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
## 2 Duster 360 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
## 3 Camaro Z28 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.84 15.41  0  0    3    4
```

**Bottom line** -- my question is: how can we filter `my_mtcars` programmatically when handed with only `filter_ref_table` to end up with `expected_output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution

```
doFilter <- function(data, criteria) {
  retVal <- data
  for (var in criteria %>% pull(var_name)) {
    crit <- criteria %>% filter(var_name == var) %>% unnest()
    minVal <- crit$min
    maxVal <- crit$max
    values <- crit$values
    if (!is.null(minVal)) {
      if (!is.na(minVal)) retVal <- retVal %>% filter(get(var) >= minVal)
    }
    if (!is.null(maxVal)) {
      if (!is.na(maxVal)) retVal <- retVal %>% filter(get(var) <= maxVal)
    }
    if (!is.null(values[[1]])) {
      if (length(values[[1]]) > 0) retVal <- retVal %>% filter(get(var) %in% values[[1]])
    }
  }
  return(retVal)
}

my_mtcars %>% doFilter(filter_ref_table)
```

Giving

```
        cars  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1    Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
2 Duster 360 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
3 Camaro Z28 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.84 15.41  0  0    3    4
```

The key is the use of `get()` to convert the character column names to objects and thus fit in with the tidyverse's NSE.

As an aside, your use of `NA`, `NULL` and zero-length lists to represent "do nothing" was slightly awkward.

**CORRECTION and edit**

My original code above fails to filter on `value`.  The fix is obvious and easy.  My apologies.

To answer OP's question in the comments and to expand on my final sentence...

If your filter dataset looked something like this:

```
carList <- c("Maserati Bora", "Chrysler Imperial", "Toyota Corona", "Merc 450SE", 
  "Lincoln Continental", "Mazda RX4", "Valiant", "Hornet 4 Drive", 
  "Fiat X1-9", "Camaro Z28", "Fiat 128", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
  "Merc 240D", "Duster 360")
anotherFilterTable <- tibble(
  var_name = c("disp", "wt", "gear", "carb", "mpg",        "cars", "drat"),
  value=     c(    NA,   NA,      3,     NA,    NA,            NA,     NA),
  min=       c(    NA,  3.4,     NA,     NA,    NA,            NA,     NA),
  max=       c(    NA,  3.9,     NA,     NA,    NA,            NA,     NA),
  choices=   c(    NA,   NA,     NA,     NA,    NA, list(carList),     NA)
) 

anotherFilterTable
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  var_name value   min   max choices   
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
1 disp        NA  NA    NA   <lgl [1]> 
2 wt          NA   3.4   3.9 <lgl [1]> 
3 gear         3  NA    NA   <lgl [1]> 
4 carb        NA  NA    NA   <lgl [1]> 
5 mpg         NA  NA    NA   <lgl [1]> 
6 cars        NA  NA    NA   <chr [15]>
7 drat        NA  NA    NA   <lgl [1]>
```

Then we've removed one level of nesting and the doFilter function can become (this time filtering on `value` as well as the other criteria)...

```
doFilter <- function(data, criteria) {
  retVal <- data
  for (var in criteria %>% pull(var_name)) {
    crit <- criteria %>% filter(var_name == var)
    if (!is.na(crit$value)) retVal <- retVal %>% filter(get(var) == crit$value)
    if (!is.na(crit$min)) retVal <- retVal %>% filter(get(var) >= crit$min)
    if (!is.na(crit$max)) retVal <- retVal %>% filter(get(var) <= crit$max)
    if (!is.na(crit$choices)) {
      retVal <- retVal %>% filter(get(var) %in% crit$choices[[1]])
    }
  }
  return(retVal)
}
```

This is slightly shorter and, to my mind, easier to read.

Both this solution and the OP's original problem statement implicitly assume a fixed set of possible filtering criteria.  (The OP's problem statement also assumes fixed column names.) To allow greater flexibility - perhaps allowing for different criteria to be applied to the same column in different datasets, then something like

```
anotherFilterTable %>% 
  mutate(across(c(value, min, max), as.list)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=c(value, min, max, choices),
    names_to="criterion",
    values_to="value"
  ) %>% 
  add_column(source="my_mtcars")
# A tibble: 28 x 4
   var_name criterion value     source   
   <chr>    <chr>     <list>    <chr>    
 1 disp     value     <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
 2 disp     min       <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
 3 disp     max       <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
 4 disp     choices   <lgl [1]> my_mtcars
 5 wt       value     <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
 6 wt       min       <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
 7 wt       max       <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
 8 wt       choices   <lgl [1]> my_mtcars
 9 gear     value     <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
10 gear     min       <dbl [1]> my_mtcars
# … with 18 more rows
```

might do. `doFilter()` would need to be modified accordingly, or course.  I think this format would also allow the definition of *arbitrary* filtering criteria (for example "only those rows whose `mpg` is in the 1st quartile of `mpg` values") to be specified without the need to modify the `doFilter()` function every time a new poteintial criterion was defined.

As always, it's a trade-off between flexibility and complexity.  The OP will need to decide where the optimum lies.